# Javascript - modify date objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

I'm receiving from a MongoDB Api an array with some expected results :

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6108f221faf75fa7899e476c"
    },
    "id": {
        "$numberInt": "7"
    },
    "item1": "XX",
    "item2": "YY",
    "item3": "ZZ",
    "itemdate1": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    "itemdate2": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    
    "itemdate5": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    "itemdate4": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
   },
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6108f2219d0f3c7c8b188607"
    },
    "id": {
        "$numberInt": "11"
    },
    "item1": "AA",
    "item2": "BB",
    "item3": "CC",
    "itemdate1": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    "itemdate2": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    
    "itemdat3": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
    "itemdate4": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
        }
    },
   }
```

]

This is just an example, I may receive 20 or 30 of those, and there are also more items.

I can't find a way to iterate through the date objects and to modify those date objects to remove the $date $ numberlong fields to get at the end, the same array but just with the date (like the following) :

`"itemdate1" : "1627976225150"`

instead of

```
"itemdate1": {
    "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
    }
},
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm assuming you're not using the [MongoDB Node Driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) which should do the date conversion for you. Is there a reason you're not? If so, I can write some recursive code to do the transform...

Comment: Hi @edemaine I'm using mongodb Realm as and API, and I receive directly those kind of requests.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/data-types/field-types/ says that the Realm SDK should support dates. Did you use `"date"` in your schema?

Comment: no, I did not totally created the schema. I will ckeck in that way.

Comment: @edemaine, I checked, but that's does not apply to me, as I'm using the third party from MongoDB Realm to generate an api.

Answer (score 0):

The objects you're working with are in a format called [EJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/json-and-bson/).  If they're still strings, you should be able to parse them via `EJSON.parse(string)`. If not, you could convert them back to JSON and then parse them, like so: `EJSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))`.

Answer (score 0):

[Mongo.db EJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) preserves types that JSON doesn't, so has special structures for things like dates. If you don't have an EJSON parser, you can use a [*reviver* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#examples) to convert objects back to their original type.

So I'm guessing that for:

```
"itemdate2": {
  "$date": {
    "$numberLong": "1627976225150"
  }
},
```

The parser should return a Date object, not the time value. Dates might be encoded as a time value or ISO 8601 string, so the reviver should deal with both. An example is below.

```js
let data = '[{"_id":{"$oid":"6108f221faf75fa7899e476c"},"id":{"$numberInt":"7"},"item1":"XX","item2":"YY","item3":"ZZ","itemdate1":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate2":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate5":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate4":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}}},{"_id":{"$oid":"6108f2219d0f3c7c8b188607"},"id":{"$numberInt":"11"},"item1":"AA","item2":"BB","item3":"CC","itemdate1":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate2":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate3":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}},"itemdate4":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1627976225150"}}}]';

let obj = JSON.parse(data, (key, value) => 
  value.$date? new Date(
    typeof value.$date == 'object'? Number(value.$date.$numberLong) : value.$date
  ) : value
);

console.log(obj);
```

If you really do want to just return the string value, then the body of the reviver can be:

```
value.$date? (value.$date.$numberLong || value.$date) : value
```